# change ID for treeview list

Tags: python, python-2.7

So here's my problem, I am trying to link a list of objects to a treeview list so that when the user clicks on one of the line in the tree he gets all the informations about the object.

So here is the code that generates the objects:

```
class CHARACTER:
    def __init__(self, name, surname, age, sexe, pragmatism,
        courage, intelligence, shyness, happiness, fear, hunger,
        comfort, feeling, companion, father, mother, kids,
        brothers_sisters, friends, compatibility):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname
        self.age = age
        self.sexe = sexe
        self.pragmatism = pragmatism
        self.courage = courage
        self.intelligence = intelligence
        self.shyness = shyness
        self.happiness = happiness
        self.fear = fear
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.comfort = comfort
        self.feeling = feeling
        self.companion = companion
        self.father = father
        self.mother = mother
        self.kids = kids
        self.brothers_sisters = brothers_sisters
        self.friends = friends
        self.compatibility = compatibility

characters = []
sexe = ["Male", "Female"]
potential_husbands = []
potential_wives = []
potential_kids = []

mname = ["John", "Mike", "Albert", "Henry", "Patrick", "Francis",
"Robert", "Simon", "Charles", "Charlie", "Connor", "Adam", "Blake", 
"Steven", "Edward", "Andrew", "Joe", "Gregory", "Brian", "Anthony", 
"Frank", "Billy", "Boris", "Edgar", "Elliott", "Erik", "Liam", "Kyron", 
"Ned", "Neil", "Ricky", "Ross", "Rich", "Roy", "Preston", "William", 
"Vladimir", "Zach", "Wyatt", "Tylor", "Thomas", "Spike"]

fname = ["Alessia", "Ally", "Bridgette", "Callie", "Jessica", 
"Debora", "Diana", "Elizabeth", "Clair", "Fran", "Hannah", 
"Helene", "Marie", "Laura", "Leslie", "Leyla", "Kiley", 
"Margaret", "Lola", "Maryjane", "Megan", "Rose", "Sofia", 
"Samantha", "Teresa", "Yolanda", "Teri", "Vicky", "Tricia", 
"Rose", "Rita", "Nita", "Paola", "Penelope", "Polly", 
"Nathalie", "Melody", "Morgane"]

lname = ["Smith", "Johnson", "Williams", "Jones", "Brown", "Miller", 
"Moore", "Taylor", "Thomas", "White", "Harris", "Thompson", "Garcia", 
"Allen", "Lewis", "Hall", "Young", "Clark", "Hill", "Lopez", "Carter", 
"Turner", "Collins", "Evans", "Campbell", "Nelson", "Parker", "Green", 
"Black", "Green", "Lee", "Martin"]


"""
Generates 20 random characters with stats
"""

def characters_creation():
    for i in range(20):
        character = CHARACTER(random.choice(lname),
        random.choice(mname), random.randint(1,50), 
        random.choice(sexe), random.randint(1,20), random.randint(1,20),
        random.randint(1,20), random.randint(1,20),
        random.randint(1,20), random.randint(1,20),
        random.randint(1,20), random.randint(1,20), {}, [], [], [],
        [], [], [], {})

        characters.append(character)
```

And the code for my treeview:

```
class CTABLE:
    def __init__(self, master):

        self.charactersTable = ttk.Treeview(master, selectmode="browse")
        self.charactersTable["show"] = "headings"
        self.charactersTable["columns"]=("Name", "Surname", "Hunger",
            "Fear", "Comfort", "Hapiness")
        self.charactersTable.column("Name", width=100, anchor=E)
        self.charactersTable.heading("Name", text="Name")
        self.charactersTable.column("Surname", width=100, anchor=E)
        self.charactersTable.heading("Surname", text="Surname")
        self.charactersTable.column("Hunger", width=100, anchor=E)
        self.charactersTable.heading("Hunger", text="Hunger")
        self.charactersTable.column("Fear", width=100, anchor=E)
        self.charactersTable.heading("Fear", text="Fear")
        self.charactersTable.column("Comfort", width=100, anchor=E)
        self.charactersTable.heading("Comfort", text="Comfort")
        self.charactersTable.column("Hapiness", width=100, anchor=E)
        self.charactersTable.heading("Hapiness", text="Hapiness")

        for character in characters:
            self.charactersTable.insert("", "end", values=(character.surname, character.name, 
            character.hunger, character.fear, character.comfort,
            character.happiness))
        self.charactersTable.bind("<Double-1>", self.CTClick)
        self.charactersTable.grid(row=1, rowspan=3, column=1)

    def CTClick(self, event):

        item = self.charactersTable.selection()[0]
        item = int(item[1:])
        print characters[item-1].surname
        print characters[item-1].name
```

So the code takes the id for each line and associate it with the character in the "character list".

Now my problem is that for some reason once I reach line 10, the program starts naming the other lines with letters instead of continuing.

So the list of ids goes like this:

[Python treeview list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YogwV.jpg)
You can see in the back on the consol what happens if I click on each line one after the other. Python switchs to letters after 9 for a few lines and then goes back to the normal count....

How can I fix this? Is there a way to manually assign a new id?

Comment: Where are you using the objects' ids? Where are you associating id with characters? Please post a [mcve]. The entire code is the important part.

Comment: The IDs are in [hexadecimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal) - is there an actual problem or are you just confused about hexadecimal values?

Comment: Well the problem is that it doesn't work with my code. Is there a way to change that so that the id's are just numbers (like a normal 1,2,3,4 etc...count)

Comment: This part of my code:

  item = int(item[1:])
  print characters[item-1].surname
  print characters[item-1].name

Doesn;t work with an hexadecimal count as it doesn't match the count of my characters list

Answer (score 1):

Alright found the answer:

```
item = self.charactersTable.selection()[0]
item = int(item[1:], 16)
print characters[item-1].surname
print characters[item-1].name
```

To convert the hex value into a decimal value (if anyone with the same problem runs into that post)

Comment: This should have been posted as an edit to the question.